# Unable to access external library classes in android test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-library

I am writing a library module (lets call Lib A) which in turn depends on the another library (Lib B) which I am adding as an external library.
While writing the test cases for Library A, I am not able to access the classes of Library B in unit testing.

I have tried following:
testImplementation project(':B') but didn't helped

implementation project (':B')
testImplementation project(':B')